# What is the correct way to set up occupation for single atom in CFOUR software?

Tags: ab-initio-calculations, symmetry, orbitals, cfour

I am doing some calculations on single oxygen atom (O) using CFOUR. According to a previous [answer](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/12587/1554) to this [question](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/12582/1554) and according to how CFOUR treats non-Abelian groups, I am considering the (O) atom to belong to the $D_{2h}$ point group. In the ZMAT input file, I should provide the OCCUPATION tag, according to the [documentation](https://cfour.uni-mainz.de/cfour/index.php?n=Main.ListOfKeywordsInAlphabeticalOrder), this tag the stands for the number of occupied orbitals of each symmetry type.

For the (O) atom,  which has an electron configuration of $1s^22s^22p^4$ and according to the character table found in this [answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/91350/50844) I am assigning the following values `OCCUPATION=2-1-1-1-0-0-0-0/2-1-0-0-0-0-0-0`. Based on what I understood the first four irreducible representations should correspond to $A_g$,$B_{3u}$,$B_{2u}$,and $B_{1u}$ in the order of $s$,$p_x$,$p_y$,$p_z$ orbitals, I have added (1) in the $\beta$ sets of orbitals since $p_x$ is holding 2 electrons with spin up and spin down. However, I have doubts in my understanding, any guidence would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your setting is incorrect for the dominant Slater determinant when calculating the electronic ground state of an O atom:

```
OCCUPATION=2-1-1-1-0-0-0-0/2-1-0-0-0-0-0-0
```

Notice that for the N atom, as described here: [When orbitals are labeled based on their irreps in D2h, how are the orbitals ordered for an N atom?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/12576/5), we had:

```
OCCUPATION=2-1-1-0-1-0-0-0/2-0-0-0-0-0-0-0
```

This is the hint that the D2h irreps in [cfour](/questions/tagged/cfour) correspond to the following orbitals:

```
OCCUPATION=s-p-p-0-p-0-0-0/s-0-0-0-0-0-0-0
```

For the element O, you have correctly added one beta electron in a p-orbital, but you have put one of the alpha p-electrons in a different irrep.

A correct setting for an O atom, would be the following:

```
OCCUPATION=2-1-1-0-1-0-0-0/2-1-0-0-0-0-0-0
```

Comment: +1, thank you for the answer, but excuse me that I am still not clear why the representation would be s-p-p-0-p-0-0-0 for the alpha electrons?

Comment: The authors of CFOUR decided that order.